Equivalence of finite expectation
Here is the question I am working on:

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are i.i.d. random variables. Prove that the following are equivalent:
(a) $\frac{X_n}{n} \rightarrow 0$ a.s.
(b) $\mathbb{E}|X_1| < \infty$

I know how to show (b) $\implies$ (a) using SLLN, but I am having trouble showing (a) $\implies$ (b). Any help is appreciated.

As stated, this is not true. Please edit to correct. Example:  consider $X_1=X_2=\dots = 1$. IID, (b) holds, but (a) doesn't (limit is $1$, not $0$).

@Fnacool $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ a.s.

Stand corrected.  Was thinking of partial sums.

Indeed, can use LLN for $(b)\Rightarrow (a)$, but this can be done also through Borel Cantelli.
Observe first that  $\frac{X_n}{n} \to 0$ a.s. Holds if and only if for
$$P(\underset{=A_\epsilon}{\underbrace{|X_n| \ge \epsilon n \mbox{ i.o.}}})=0 \mbox{ for every }\epsilon>0.$$
Let's set this up for the Borel-Cantelli Lemmas.
Since $X_n$ has the same distribution as $X_1$, we have
\begin{align*}  \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_n| \ge \epsilon n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty P(|X_1| \ge \epsilon n)=(*)\end{align*}
Clearly,
$$ \frac{1}{\epsilon} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{k\epsilon}^{(k+1) \epsilon} P(|X_1| \ge s) ds \le (*) \le  \frac{1}{\epsilon} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_{k\epsilon}^{(k+1) \epsilon} P(|X_1| \ge s) ds.$$
As $\int_0^\infty P(|X_1|\ge s) ds = E[|X_1|]$, we have that
$$ \frac1{\epsilon} E[|X_1|]-1\le  (*) \le \frac{1}{\epsilon} E[ |X_1|].$$
Therefore $(*)<\infty$ (regardless of $\epsilon$) if and only if $E[|X_1|]<\infty$. Now:

According to the first BC lemma:  $$(*)<\infty ~ \Rightarrow P(A_\epsilon)=0$$
According to the second BC lemma (this is the only place we use the independence of the $X_n$'s), $$(*)=\infty~\Rightarrow  P(A_\epsilon)=1.$$

As a conclusion,$\frac{X_n}{n}=0$ a.s. if and only if $P(A_\epsilon)=0$ for every $\epsilon>0$ if and only if $E[|X_1|]<\infty$.
